# Pass text value of lookup to jscontroller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lookup, lightninginput

I have a lookup component in lightning. The parent component code snippet

```
<th class="slds-align-bottom"><c:LookupCmp objectName="User"
                                      field_API_text="Name"
                                      field_API_val="Id"
                                      field_API_search="Name"
                                      lookupIcon="standard:product" 
                                      selItem="{!v.assignedto}" 
                                      placeholder="Enter Assigned To"
                            /></th> 
                            <!--Hidden Input Field used to pass the lookup value-->
                            <aura:if isTrue="{! not(empty(v.assignedto)) }"> 
                                <lightning:input aura:id = "assignedToInput" value ="{#v.assignedto.text}" /><br />
                            </aura:if>
```

Here the value "{#v.assignedto.text}" is correctly holding the text of lookup value selected within the lightning input. However I am unable to pass it to the jscontroller as I am not being able to tag it to any attribute. Is there any way to achieve this

Comment: have you tried component.find('aura:id').get('v.value') ?  [Working with Attribute Values in JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_attr_values.htm)

Comment: This totally works and I was constantly trying with component.find('aura:id').value which was definitely not working. Please provide this as an answer. So, I can mark it as correct. @glls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented in [Working with Attribute Values in JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_attr_values.htm)

try using:

```
component.find('aura:id').get('v.value')
```

Practical Example from the doc:

component.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="buttonLabel" type="String"/>
    <lightning:button aura:id="button1" label="Button 1"/>
    {!v.buttonLabel}
    <lightning:button label="Get Label" onclick="{!c.getLabel}"/>
</aura:component>
```

component.js

```
({
    getLabel : function(component, event, helper) {
        var myLabel = component.find("button1").get("v.label");
        component.set("v.buttonLabel", myLabel);
    }
})
```